# Not loading a view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

here is a small peice off code that i wrote. But I am not getting the data in the view. It says undefined variable in the view

Controller

```
$data= array(); 
$data['']= json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/api/colleges'));
$this->load->view('colleges/index',$data);
```

View

```
 foreach($data as $college) : 
 ?>
<ul>
    <li><label>ID:</label> <?php echo $college;?></li>
</ul>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

Controller:
    $data['colleges']= json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/api/colleges'));

View:
    foreach($colleges as $college)

Comment: I would like to know the reason for it?

Comment: What you are doing here is loading up data with everything you will need for the view, that is pretty much the job of the controller. You could call it $view_data if that helps readability. Codeignitor uses extract() before including the view template so the variables are available, else you would have scope issues.

Comment: See here: http://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L832

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter *translates* the $data array into variables based on their key to be used in your view.

So, if (in your controller) you had:

```
$data['poop'] = "Poop is stinky."
```

Then, in your view, you won't be using $data, you'll be using

```
echo $poop;
// Poop is stinky.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use:
array_push($data,json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/api/colleges'))

or you need to specify an index for $data e.g. $data[0]